# Is there an efficient algorithm to this problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Let $f_{i}$ be $n$ strictly decreasing, continuous functions on the positive real numbers with
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f_{i} = \infty
$$

Let $I$ be a positive real number.

I think I can prove that there always exists a unique set of $n$ non-negative $x_{i}$ that sum to $I$ and that have:

$$
f_{i}(x_{i}) = f_{j}(x_{j}) 
$$

for all $i,j$ in ${1,...,n}$

I think the greedy algorithm gives a solution to this problem, but is there anything better? In particular, is there a closed solution?

Comment: Did you mean that $f_i$ are strictly increasing? If $f_i$ functions are strictly decreasing, then how would $\lim_{x\to\infty} f_i(x) = \infty$?

Comment: If it's not necessarily decreasing, then it's definetly not true for every $I>0$. Example: $I = 1$, $f_1(x) = x^2$, $f_2(x) = 4 + x^2$. Then for $f_1(x_2) = f_2(x_1) \ge 4 \implies f_1(x_2) \ge 4 \implies x_2\ge2$. So $x_1+x2 \ge 2 > I$. Which means that there is no such $x_1, x_2$

Comment: I think you've misread the limits. The limit is as x tends to 0.

Comment: Do you know the inverse functions?

Comment: Nope - all you know are the values of $f$

Comment: The closed form solution is $g^{-1}(I)$ where $g(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}^{-1}(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use theg reedy algo here. A fairly simple way of doing it is by using the inverse functions.

If you know the inverse functions, you can apply a root finding/minimization algo for:
$$I = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i^{-1}(y) \implies I - \sum_{i=1}^{n} |f_i^{-1}(y)| = 0$$.

If you don't know the inverse, you can get the inverse values by an extra root finding/minimization for each of the functions in the form of $|f_i(x_i) - y| = 0$.